# Value of type 'EventsController' has no member 'navBarController'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a swift newbie and cant figure this out. I have in my navbar controller a function setupNavigationBarItems that I'm trying to call in my EventsController that has all the buttons in my toolbar so i dont have to duplicate my code.

```
import UIKit

class EventsController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         var navBarController: NavBarController!

         self.view.backgroundColor = .white

         self.navBarController.navbar.setupNavigationBarItems()

     }

     func showEventsController() {
          let eventsController = EventsController()
          eventsController.navBarController = self // THIS :)
          self.present(eventsController, animated: true, completion: 
          nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: the line that errors is 
     self.navBarController.navbar.setupNavigationBarItems()
and 
    eventsController.navBarController = self

Comment: first you need declare your  `var navBarController: NavBarController!` outside the viewDidLoad scope, also I think you are missing the variable initialization

Comment: Events controller is an UIViewController defined in storyboard?, if is yes your answer, then you must initialize your eventController with storyboard.instaciateViewController method

Comment: its not, i dont use a storyboard, im trying to do everything programmatically

Comment: the error for the second line is : cannot assign value of type 'EventsController' to type 'NavBarController!

Comment: Of course because you are assigning self which is `EventsController` class object and the receiver is waiting an object of type `NavBarController`

Comment: im sorry i dont really understand what that means